# How can I listen to a event in Odoo 16 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I would like to listen for the event of a field in Odoo 16 using JavaScript. I have attempted the following code snippets, but I get an error.

this is my assets.xml view:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="circulacion assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/circulacion/static/src/js/assets.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

this is my javascript file
circulacion/static/src/js/assets.js

```
odoo.define('circulacion.campo_nit', function (require) {
    
"use strict";
    var fieldRegistry = require('web.field_registry');
    var FieldChar = require('web.basic_fields').InputField;

    var CampoNit = FieldChar.extend({
        events: _.extend({}, FieldChar.prototype.events, {
            'keypress': '_onKeyPress',
        }),

        _onKeyPress: function (event) {
            var input = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (!/[0-9C/F]/.test(input)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
    });

    fieldRegistry.add('campo_nit', CampoNit);

    return CampoNit;
});
```

In my form view, I use the widget campo_nit

```
<field name="nit" widget="campo_nit" />
```

in manyfest.py :

```
"depends": ["base",],
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
                'circulacion/static/src/js/assets.js',
            ]
    },
    # always loaded
    "data": [
        "views/assets.xml",
        "security/ir.model.access.csv",
        "views/views.xml",
        "views/templates.xml",
        
    ],
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message and whole Traceback please ?

Comment: Could you add console.log(event); in your js function: _onKeyPress?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your manifest file:

you should remove or comment **#"views/assets.xml"** in **'data' : [...**  because the correct way since v15 is to set it only in your manifest in its **'assets' : {...** (already done by you):

```py
'assets': {  'web.assets_backend': [ 'circulacion/static/src/js/assets.js', ]  },

"data": [  
      #"views/assets.xml",
        "security/ir.model.access.csv",
        "views/views.xml",
        "views/templates.xml",        
    ],
```

Could you provide the error message and whole Traceback please ?

Could you add console.log(event); in your js function: _onKeyPress ?